# Accessing Static Variable from child->child class php

Tags: php, oop, static, static-variables

I have the following setup:

```
<?php
class core {
    static $var1;
}

class parent extends core {
   function getStatic() {
       return parent::$var1;
   }
}

class child extends parent {
    function getStatic() {
        // I want to access core static var, how can i do it?
        //return parent::$var1;
   }
}
?>
```

I need to be able to use parent::$var1 but from within class child.. is this possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reference it as self...  PHP will automatically go up the chain of inheritance until it finds a match

```
class core {
    protected static $var1 = 'foo';
}
class foo extends core {
    public static function getStatic() {
        return self::$var1;
    }
}
class bar extends foo {
    public static function getStatic() {
        return self::$var1;
    }
}
```

Now, there will be an issue if you don't declare getStatic in bar.  Let's take an example:

```
class foo1 extends core {
    protected static $var1 = 'bar';
    public static function getStatic() {
        return self::$var1;
    }
}
class bar1 extends foo1 {
    protected static $var1 = 'baz';
}
```

Now, you'd expect `foo1::getStatic()` to return `bar` (and it will).  But what will `Bar1::getStatic()` return?  It'll return `bar` as well.  This is called late static binding.  If you want it to return `baz`, you need to use `static::$var1` instead of `self::$var1` (PHP 5.3+ only)...

Answer (score 2):

core::$var1 seems best for your needs...

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem here is that you're using the keyword parent as a class name. This makes it completely ambiguous whether your calls to parent::$var1 are intended to point to that class, or to the parent of the calling class.

I believe, if you clean this up, you can achieve what you want. This code prints 'something', for example.

```
class core {
    static $var1 = 'something';
}

class foo extends core {
   function getStatic() {
       return parent::$var1;
   }
}

class bar extends foo {
    function getStatic() {
        // I want to access core static var, how can i do it?
        return parent::$var1;
   }
}

$b = new bar ();
echo $b->getStatic ();
```

It also works if you use `core::` instead of `parent::`. Those two *will* behave differently, though, if you declare a static $var1 inside of the `foo` class as well. As is it's a single, inherited variable.

Comment: I will check this out, BTW, Its not actually called `parent` that's just a bad example.

Comment: `parent` is a reserved keyword, PHP won't let you call your class `parent`.